# Warning message when trying to change Standby mode settings

Tags: macos, terminal, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I tried changing the Standby mode settings using the command `sudo pmset -a standbydelay 5400` . I set it to 5400 so that it is delayed to 1.5 hours compared to 70 minutes as default.

However, I get the following message right after I changed it :

`Warning: Idle sleep timings for "Battery Power" may not behave as expected.
- Disk sleep should be non-zero whenever system sleep is non-zero.`

What does this mean ?? Must I change the value back to 4200 ?

*edit*

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         5400
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            0
 sleep                180
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `pmset -g`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the output of `pmset -g`, you have your system set to sleep after 2 hours, but the disk sleep timer is set to zero--meaning never according to the [`pmset` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html). To correct the error, set `disksleep` to a value greater than zero but less than (or equal to) `sleep`.

Use something like the following with your preferred `disksleep` time,

```
pmset -a disksleep 45
```

to set `disksleep` to 45 minutes for all power situations.  You may want to adjust these times for when your MBPr is running on battery.  Set battery profiles with `-b` instead of `-a`.

I think you'll benefit greatly from the [`pmset` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html). It's very clear and You'll probably discover something else that pertains to your needs there.

Comment: Hmm Disk Sleep is related to the option `Put hard disks to sleep when possible` .. However I disabled that because I have SSD instead of HDD, so I do not really need that option (according to sources I read online) .. Does the warning message indicate that a severe problem might appear later on ?

Comment: I know what you mean. It doesn't appear to make sense, but apparently you can't have the system sleep without the disks sleeping ?

Comment: This is just to work around your error based on what `pmset` expects.

Comment: Hmm yeah, interesting. I read the `pmset man page`, thanks for the link. What would happen if I ignored the warning message ?

Comment: Since you have an SSD, I think it's safe to ignore.  This option is infinitely more important for HDDs.